# Refactor haml to use rails link_to helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have the following haml markup:

```
%a.logo-text{href: "/surveys"}
    %b Survey
    Builder
```

Is there any way of rewriting this to use Ruby on Rails `link_to` helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a block to link_to helper:

```
= link_to "/surveys", class: "logo-text" do
  %b Survey
  Builder
```

or in one line:

```
= link_to "<b>Survey</b>Builder".html_safe, "/surveys", class: "logo-text"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
= link_to '/surveys', class: 'logo-text' do
  %b Survey
  Builder
```

In a single line:

```
= link_to raw('<b>Survey</b>Builder'), '/surveys', class: 'logo-text'
```

Comment: Very close, but there is one issue. Between Survey and Builder should not be any space.